# TYPO3: TypoScript override if condition with and

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a TypoScript layout and need an if statement with a second inside

```
stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="grid col1 lay{field:layout}">|</div>
```

now set the override with if header_layout is not set to 100:

```
stdWrap.dataWrap.override = <div class="header"><h4>{field:header}</h4><h5>{field:subheader}</h5></div><span class="hitter"></span><div class="grid col1 lay{field:layout}">|</div>
stdWrap.dataWrap.override.if{
    value = 100
    equals.field = header_layout
    negate = 1
```

that worked, but if no header is set, the user don't set header_layout to hidden so i want to check if the field header is not empty, but this doesn't work:

```
stdWrap.dataWrap.override.if{
    value = 100
    equals.field = header_layout
    negate = 1
    isTrue.cObject = TEXT
    isTrue.cObject{
        value = 1
        if.value = 
        equals.field = header
        negate = 1
```

If the header is set and header_layout is 100, the simple output is rendered but if the header is empty and header_layout is not 100 the override will be rendered and add empty html tags.

I think the second condition will seen as "or" and not as "and", how should this TypoScript look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple conditions you have to watch for global modifiers like `.negate`, they can't be assigned to single conditions but on the whole result of all single conditions which are combined by `and`.
As far as I understand your logic I think that you missed to negate  your cascaded `.if`. You also can avoid comparison to `empty` if you use the appropriate condition (`.isTrue` or because of negation `.isFalse`)

Otherwise you might need to build a complex condition.

There are a lot of options:

- use multiple combinations of `.ifempty`, `.override`, `.if`
- use `COA` either for your values or your condition, where every simple condition is assigned to one array object:

```
temp.test = COA
temp.test {
   10 = TEXT
   10 {
      value = cond1
      if {
         value = 1
         equals.field = abc
      }
   }
   20 = TEXT
   20 {
      value = cond2
      if {
         value = 2
         equals.field = def
      }
   }
}
```

then you could use it as is or use it to build the correct condition:

AND:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value = my value
10.ovreride = my override
10.override.if {
   value =cond1cond2
   equals.cObject < temp.test
}
```

OR:

```
10 = TEXT
10.value = my value
10.override = my override
10.override.if.isTrue.cObject < temp.test
```

Comment: "there is no defined behaviour if you add multiple conditions to an .if." is not correct.
TSref for `if` is saying: "This function returns true, if ALL of the present conditions are met (they are connected with an “AND”, a logical conjunction)." (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/If.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Explanation in the [TSref](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/If.html?highlight=istrue#explanation), conditions are connected with an `AND`.

So these very simple conditions should match:

- `header_layout` must be less than 100
- `header` has to be "true" (=not empty)

As TypoScript:

```
stdWrap.dataWrap.override.if {
  value = 100
  isLessThan.field = header_layout
  isTrue.field = header
}
```

Comment: 100 is hidden, 0-99 are Layouts. I changed isGreaterThan to isLessThan they do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: You're right. I'm always a bit confused about which value is on which side of the operator... And stripping the `negate` didN#t make it easier... (I fixed it)